# Apply easing effect to SlideUp and SlideDown function

Tags: jquery, slideup, jquery-easing

I applied the following function to hide the header when the user scrolls downs, and show it again when they scroll up:

```
    var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ($(this).width() < 768) {
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
        }
    } 
          } 

        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
```

It works like a charm, but I wanted to apply an easing effect, since the animation is rough, but I failed to succeed so far.

Thank you in advance for you help.

P.s. Sorry, but I forgot to mention that my jquery knowledge is very limited.

**EDIT:**

I decided go with a different function, but even though it works fine on codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNOgeb), on jsfiddle doesn't (https://jsfiddle.net/8bdhzzLb/) and I suppose it's because the Jquery libray is automatically loaded on CodePen, but not in JSfiddle.

I've tried to include the src you provided, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunatly the easings are only available with the jQuery-UI-Library. According to the jQuery-Docs:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called `swing`, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   `linear`

So the following code only works with jQuery-UI in addition:

```
 $('#header-wrap').slideUp({ 
     duration: 5000, 
     easing: "easeInOutQuart" 
 });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dvkv61u8/)

**Reference**

[jQuery UI easings](http://jqueryui.com/easing/)

Comment: Thanks,

I've implemented the code you provided, but now the function no longer works unfortunately.

Comment: Include jquery UI if you want to use easeInOutQuart easing (which you do, its cool). https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js

Comment: @Marrone As Sully said, please check if you have included the jQuery-UI-Library to use the easings.

Comment: Thanks empiric, I've included Sully's src code as well, but now the function no longer works.

Comment: @Marrone have a look at [this](http://jsbin.com/qabitonami/1/edit?html,css,js,output) example

Comment: I've changed the code, but it seems to work on only on Codepen as the JQuery library is automatically loaded I supposed. IN JSfidde, in fact, it doesn't work. Which src code do I have to add to my header?

Comment: Look at the example, there is all src-code included in the header-section

Comment: I did include the src code, but still no results: http://jsbin.com/recaxafiwi/1/edit

Comment: @Marrone I updated your [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/jizamebola/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks empiric, this solves the issue. However it's not exactly the same effect I wanted to achieve (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNOgeb). As you can see, here the inner div and its text slides down/up along with the header. In your version, it's actually fixed. Thanks again for your help.